# Multiple store Payment Gateway issue and Paypal Currency Issue

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, multistore, paypal-express

I have Multiple stores with Domain and subdoamin. I am facing a Strange error. in my multistore domains all payment gateway is working fine. But if i am using same on my subdomains multiple store its redirecting on main website. rather then same subdomain checkout page.

Second qus is My base currency is INR but one my store i am using USD tried to checkout with Payment its giving currency Not Supported issue.

Please Guide me